# Unexpected token ( , when calling variables from stacked functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

## Issue

When stacking multiple functions together and trying to access variables from each other, console returns **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (**

==================================================

## Explaining Functions

$(window).load(function() {, to load all functions simultaneously. Is this being used correctly?

**Function toggleTabContent**: Grabs the NavLink ID from **setup function**, and toggles main-wrapper sections based on data attribute (data-sidebar-tab) of variable currentNavSection declared in **goto function** (Explained in goto)

**Function setup**: Gets the ID (Parent) of the **current, clicked** Nav Link, being a nav-element for porpoises of highlighting the icon on :active and hover, and having a side border that slides depending on offset. (Explained in animateBorder)

**Function animateBorder**: Uses function currentNavElement, from **setup function** to determine the offset for the border. Hence, `var navPosition = $(currentNavElement).offset()`. The result is stored in a variable called navPosition. A variable called navBorder then determines that offset of the navigation element (parent of link) cannot have a CSS Top Property of 0.

Moving navBorder is then done using the CSS Property "top", based on the nav-element's offset (y).

**Function goto**: Gets the current section active $(this), then combines it by "#" + 
clicked id on the nav from **function setup**

## **Edited Code** Follow up from @Dante

1. alert(currentNavElement) returns undefined.
2. Are the functions communicated as originally intended?

   ```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   setup(function(currentNavElement){
       toggleTabContent(currentNavElement);
       goto(currentNavElement);
       animateBorder(currentNavElement);
       alert(currentNavElement)
   });
   });

   function toggleTabContent(currentNavElement) {
   $("[data-sidebar-tab]").each(function(navPosition, currentNavSection) {
       $(currentNavSection).data("sidebar-tab") === currentNavElement ? $(currentNavSection).show() : $(currentNavSection).hide()
   })
   };
   function setup(cb) {
   $(document).delegate(".nav-element a", "click", function() {
       cb($(this).attr("id"));
   })
   };
   function animateBorder(currentNavElement) {
       var navPosition = $(currentNavElement).offset(), 
       navBorder = !!(navPosition && navPosition.top >= 0) && navPosition.top;
   if (!1 === navBorder) return !1;
       $("#nav-border").css('top', navBorder)
   };
   function goto(currentNavElement)  {
   var currentNavSection = $("#"),
       currentNavSectiona = $("#" + currentNavElement + " a");
   };
   ```

## **HTML for referencing**

```
            <ul id="nav-custom">
            <div id="nav-border"></div>
            <li id="nav-home" class="nav-element noselect">
                <a href="#" class="nav-permalink" data-permalink="content-home" data-lang-title="account_title" title="Home">
           <span class="text" data-lang="splash">Home</span>
           <i class="nav-icon material-icons">donut_large</i>
           </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <!-------------->
            SECTION EXAMPLE CODE
            <!-------------->
            <section id="content-home" class="content-style" data-sidebar-tab="home">
            </section>
```

## **Original JavaScript**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    toggleTabContent: function(currentNavElement) {
        $("[data-sidebar-tab]").each(function(navPosition, currentNavSection) {
            $(currentNavSection).data("sidebar-tab") === currentNavElement ? $(currentNavSection).show() : $(currentNavSection).hide()
        })
    },
    setup: function() {
        $(document).delegate(".nav-element a", "click", function() {
            var currentNavElement = $(this).attr("id");
        })
    },
    animateBorder: function(currentNavElement) {
            var navPosition = $(currentNavElement).offset(), 
            navBorder = !!(navPosition && navPosition.top >= 0) && navPosition.top;
        if (!1 === navBorder) return !1;
            $("#nav-border").css('top', navBorder)
    },
    goto: function(currentNavElement) {
        $(".nav-element").removeClass("active");
        var currentNavSection = $("#" + currentNavElement),
            currentNavSectiona = $("#" + currentNavElement + " a");
    }
})
```

Comment: Uh, your trying to define your `toggleTabContent` as if it was inside an object, but it's not.  It's inside a function.  Which is an object, yes, but this is invalid syntax.  `var scope = { method1: function(){} }` is valid.  `function(){ method1: function(){} }` is not valid.  The `{}` serve different purposes for the different structures.

Comment: @Taplar Alright added an object within the  $(window).load(function() {) . Should I declare the object or is there another approach I could use without an object, for the functions to work?

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` it is function that execute when the event is triggered. As soon as the all image has been loaded, the handler is called. Also this method was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 3.0 version of jQuery. More about it you events you can read here - [jQuery Events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

First of all, I will suggest you to use `.ready()` function to handle event when DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Run code
});
```

Second moment as mention by [@taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar) in comments, `function() {}` it's not an object. You should declare this functions and when use it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  toggleTabContent(el);
});

function toggleTabContent(currentNavElement) {
  // Code here
};
```

Another variant that you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var methods = {
    toggleTabContent: function() {
      // Code here
    }
  };
  methods.toggleTabContent();
});
```

In this variant we declare object `methods` with function `toggleTabContent`. Then call it `methods.toggleTabContent()`.

More about objects you can read here - [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Functions are stacked as such, ` function toggleTabContent(currentNavElement) {
        $("[data-sidebar-tab]").each(function(navPosition, currentNavSection) {
            $(currentNavSection).data("sidebar-tab") === currentNavElement ? $(currentNavSection).show() : $(currentNavSection).hide()
        })
    },`

Should the declared functions be outside of the $(document).ready(function() {} where they are being called?

Comment: Alright, following your suggestion. I have separated them as such `    $(document).ready(function() {
        toggleTabContent();
        setup()
        animateBorder()
        goto()
    });`

and the functions after them. 

My question would be, what should I put as to when they are being called? They were already called from inside the function such as function toggleTabContent(currentNavElement) {} and function animateBorder(currentNavElement) {}.

Is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @NTAuro, your function `setup()` should return `currentNavElement`, because now your function is void, it's doesn't return something. One way to do it, it is to use callback function. Implementation with `cb()` you can see here [JSFiddle - cb()](https://jsfiddle.net/m9275ny2/10/)

Comment: Alright so I did as you recommended. Its still errerous as alert outputs as undefined value when I click on a nav-element a link.

Also, are the functions linked correctly together as intended?

Please check a sample HTML section of setup between Navbar and Content Sections (applicable for toggletabcontent and navborder to change from display:none to block, and slide respectively)